# What does the existence of this file indicate?

Tags: encryption, forensics, data-recovery

C:\Documents and Settings\Sarah\Recent\DSCN0275.JPG.lnk
on a Microsoft Windows system, and use the xxd program to dump the contents of
this file:

[image: Content]

Comment: Please don't post text as an image.

Comment: Again, this too looks like a homework question. And the problem space is not defined. From everything you provided in the question, there is no obvious security angle.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a normal [shortcut file](https://fileinfo.com/help/windows_shortcuts). When you right click on a file and choose "Create Shortcut" this is the resulting file it creates.

In this case it is in the recent folder. Items are automatically made and added to the recent folder when they have been recently accessed.

There is no security concern here.